# Loops Iterations Analysis

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

I am trying to find the running time O(n) for the block of code below:

```
int z=0;
int x=0; 
for (int i=1; i<=n; i=i*3){ //runs from 1->n, 1, 3, 9, 27... <- fcn that defines this?
   //constant running times below
   z = z+5;
   z++;
   x = 2*x;
}
```

if it was i=i*2, then it would be logn complexity running time. What is it for this case?

tia.

Comment: If you can get `i = i * 2` case, then you should be able to derive the result for this case.

Comment: So, if i = i*2, and that results in 'log n' time, do you mean log base 10? log base 2? log base e?

Comment: yes Nathaniel that is correct (i meant log base 2), and no its not homework. Studying for an exam.

Comment: Do you understand why it's log base 2?

Comment: ok thanks got it, i dont have enough rep to vote. but i can accept regardless

Comment: @NathanielFord yes i do, so in this case it would be log(3) n. agreed?

Comment: I recommend you write up a solution, and if people agree they'll vote it up. Then you'll get reputation, and if enough people vote it up you'll get a badge, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that log_3 (n) = log_2 (n) /  log_2 (3) . Here log_2 means log with base 2 and log_3 means log with base 3. So, log_2(n) is just log_3(n) times a constant.

So, by big O definition, any code which has running time O(log_3(n)) is also O(log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your n was 15, that case your loop goes as follows-

1, 3, 9 = 3 times
The number of iterations is a log_3 (15)

In general the way to think about it is if you are halving or dividing your input by a third (or any fraction) and going upto 0, then it will be log base of that factor you're dividing by.

If you are halving, it will be log_2(n), if you're dividing by a third, it will be log_3(n) and so on. Hope that general idea helps